# Finetuning the SQL Query Performance

Tags: sql-server

The following query takes about 3000ms to execute.
I could not fine-tune this query to give a considerable performance edge.

```
declare @EndDate datetime;
declare @FromDate datetime;
set @EndDate = getdate();
set @FromDate = DATEADD(year,-1, @EndDate);

    SELECT [twc].ColumnId, [twc].ColumnName
    FROM [table1] twcs with(nolock)
        INNER JOIN [table2] twc with(nolock) ON [twc].ColumnId = [twcs].ColumnId 
        WHERE [twcs].[ColumnName] = 1 AND [twc].[CreateDate] between @fromdate and @enddate;
```

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any field used in a decision context (e.g. where, join, order by, case, etc...) should have an index on it.

Comment: have you looked at the estimated or actual execution plan?

Comment: nothing wrong with your query, is a simple query, you need indexes

Comment: Is `ColumnName` really in both tables?

Comment: Thanks all for your quick responses. Yes, we have ensured that the indexing is properly done and wanted to ensure that the query is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT twc.ColumnId, twc.ColumnName
FROM table1 twcs with (nolock) INNER JOIN
     table2 twc with (nolock)
     ON twc.ColumnId = twcs.ColumnId 
WHERE twcs.ColumnName = 1 AND twc.CreateDate between @fromdate and @enddate;
```

I would suggest the following indexes such as the following:

- `table2(CreateDate, ColumnId)`
- `table2(ColumnId, CreateDate)`
- `table1(ColumnName, ColumnId)`
- `table1(ColumnId, ColumnName)`

Let the optimizer choose which to use.

Answer (score 1):

With a query as simple and straight forward as that, you're likely looking at an issue where the tables need a new index to speed the return rather than script optimization.